# merge list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I have a list of lists, where some lists are NULL (contain nothing), and some lists contains 12 columns and 1 row. lets say this list of lists is named: pages.

I would like to merge the lists that contain the 12 columns and 1 row into a dataframe. so that I have a final dataframe of 12 columns and x rows.

I first tried:

```
final_df <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), pages)
```

which yielded a dataframe with the right 12 columns, but no rows, so it was empty.

I then tried:

```
listofvectors <- list()
for (i in 1:length(pages))  {listofvectors <- c(listofvectors, pages[[i]])}
```

which just pasted every list below each other.

I finally tried playing with:

```
final<-do.call(c, unlist(pages, recursive=FALSE))
```

which only resulted in a very long value.

What am I missing? Who can help me out? Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge` function is for joining data on common column values (commonly called a `join`). You need to use `rbind` instead (the *r* for row, use `cbind` to stick columns together).

```
do.call(rbind, pages) # equivalent to rbind(pages[[1]], pages[[2]], ...)
do.call(rbind, pages[lengths(pages) > 0]) # removing the 0-length elements
```

If you have additional issues, please provide a reproducible example in your question. This code works on this example:

```
x = list(data.frame(x = 1), NULL, data.frame(x = 2))
do.call(rbind, x)
#   x
# 1 1
# 2 2
```